# Is $\int_{-R}^R(t+\frac{ia}{2})^2e^{-t^2}dt=(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{a^2}{4})\int_{-R}^R e^{-t^2}dt-Re^{-R^2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $t\in [-R,R], a\in\mathbb{R}$. I want to know if the following equation holds: $$\int_{-R}^R(t+\frac{ia}{2})^2e^{-t^2}dt=(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{a^2}{4})\int_{-R}^R e^{-t^2}dt-Re^{-R^2}.$$
If I start with left hand side: $\int_{-R}^R(t+\frac{ia}{2})^2e^{-t^2}dt
=\int_{-R}^R t^2e^{-t^2}dt+ia\int_{-R}^R te^{-t^2}dt+\frac{a^2}{4}\int_{-R}^R e^{-t^2}dt=\int_{-R}^R t^2e^{-t^2}dt+\frac{a^2}{4}\int_{-R}^R e^{-t^2}dt$ 
I don't get the right hand side, therefore I think this equation is wrong. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You get the correct result in you expand your brackets correctly.. It should be $- \frac{a^{2}}{4}$ in your second line, not $+ \frac{a^{2}}{4}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_{-R}^{R} t^{2} e^{-t^{2}} dt &= \int_{-R}^{R} t (te^{-t^{2}}) dt \\
&= \frac{-1}{2} te^{-t^{2}} \bigg \lvert_{-R}^{R} + \frac{1}{2} I \\
\end{align}

where we have integrated by parts and

$$I = \int_{-R}^{R} e^{-t^{2}} dt$$

For the next term

\begin{align}
ia \int_{-R}^{R} te^{-t^{2}} dt &= -\frac{1}{2} ia e^{-t^{2}} \bigg \lvert_{-R}^{R}
\end{align}

Finally

\begin{align}
\frac{-a^{2}}{4} \int_{-R}^{R} e^{-t^{2}} dt &= \frac{-a^{2}}{4} I
\end{align}

Putting together, we have

\begin{align}
\frac{-1}{2} Re^{-R^{2}} - \frac{1}{2} Re^{-R^{2}} + \frac{1}{2} I -\frac{1}{2} ia e^{-R^{2}} + \frac{1}{2} ia e^{-R^{2}} - \frac{a^{2}}{4} I &= \bigg( \frac{1}{2} - \frac{a^{2}}{4} \bigg)I - Re^{-R^{2}} \\
\end{align}